# Python threadpool io bound tasks

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Assume following code :

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import itertools

def task_function(task_id):
    print(f"Task {task_id} started")
    time.sleep(10)  # Simulating some work
    print(f"Task {task_id} completed")

def generate_task_ids():
    # Infinite generator for task IDs
    for i in itertools.count(start=1):
        yield i

# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor with 3 threads
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    task_ids_generator = generate_task_ids()

    try:
        # Continuously submit tasks to the thread pool
        while True:
            task_id = next(task_ids_generator)
            task = executor.submit(task_function, task_id)
            time.sleep(1)  # Introduce a delay between task submissions (for demonstration)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Received KeyboardInterrupt. Stopping task submissions.")

# Main thread continues after exiting the with block
print("Main thread continues")
```

As we sleep for 10 seconds in task_function does the ThreadPoolExecutor counts this thread as free thread and submit new tasks to it effectively creating more than 3 threads ?

My goal was to mix this with asyncio to have faster io bound apps reponse but at first step i am confused how ThreadPoolExecutor works upon facing something like sleep.

Comment: No - `max_workers=3` means that there are only 3 threads alive at a time. The executor will only start another thread when one of the workers has _returned_ (rather than halted/slept).

Comment: It's also worth noting that `executor.submit()` is not blocking - it will allow you to submit 1,000,000 tasks immediately even if you only have 3 workers.

Comment: Do you know about [`asyncio.loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).  It provides a bridge between async and sync worlds that might help